# Buying Cluster/Grid/Cloud Time?

Tags: cloud, cluster-computing, grid-computing

I've used clusters in industrial and academic settings, but they were owned by the organizations I worked for. I've never purchased time from a company that sells cluster/cloud/grid time.

Suppose I want to run some compute intensive program like as a large simulation or a data mining application. Or maybe I want to optimize a complete build of a large product suite by running a distributed build on outsourced infrastructure. **Where would I purchase cluster time to run such programs?**

I'm interested in learning about clusters that run popular OS platforms like Linux, BSD, Mac OS X, and Windows.

Obviously, there is the build-your-own-cluster solution using the fast, cheap hardware available these days, but I'm specifically interested in an outsourced solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to check out Amazon's EC2 service:

http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/

Some people have already done some work in regards to clustering with EC2:

http://www.google.com/search?q=cluster+computing+amazon+ec2&rls=com.microsoft:*&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&startIndex=&startPage=1

Additionally, Microsoft has offered [Windows Azure](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/windowsazure/), which has native hooks for .NET, allows you to run anything, really (Java, php), given that you are able to load a runtime and code from storage (or deployed with your app, but that has it's own set of pros/cons).

Answer (score 2):

The site is undergoing updates at the moment but I know Sun operate such a service http://www.network.com/, its been a while since I looked at it but if I remember correctly it was quite well priced with lots of options.
I am currently using a cluster for my final year university project which has 496 cores, fortunately don't have to pay to use it :).

Answer (score 2):

Amazon's [Elastic Compute Cloud](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) is very interesting. You pay for what you use (Memory, CPU, Persisted storage) many OS options.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently really interested in **[Azure](http://www.microsoft.com/azure/default.mspx) Cloud Computing** technology by Microsoft (to be released this year) that features .NET support.

Additionally there are:

- **[Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/)** - Python framework by Google
- **[Cloud vService](http://www.vmware.com/technology/virtual-datacenter-os/cloud-vservices/)** - by VMWare
- **[Amazon Web Services](http://aws.amazon.com/)**

Answer (score 1):

There is a new service called [Amazon Elastic MapReduce](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticmapreduce/) which runs on top of EC2 cluster. It has APIs in many of the programming languages including Ruby and PHP. Also, if you need more established service, checkout [GreenPlum](http://www.greenplum.com/)